# Debugging inside a local Gitlab Runner container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to get some Rails tests working with Gitlab CI Runner by executing it locally as follows:

`gitlab-runner exec docker rspec`

The tests use headless Chrome to render an image into a directory somewhere in the container. I need to inspect this image to compare it with the expected result.

Local debug strategies such as `puts` and `byebug` are not working. What are my options?

Comment: Do I get it right you are running your test job manually on a gitlab-runner? Default approach would be to run it remotely (automatically on code changes) from repo and save the image as an artifact.

Comment: @trust512 Yes. I'm debugging locally so the test cycle is quicker. My container configuration is complex and not yet working. Once that works it's going back onto Gitlab CI. Looks like artefacts might do the trick if I test on Gitlab, but that defeats the purpose of quick cycles. Any other way to, e.g. persist the container locally with `exec`?

Comment: @trust512 I've tried doing this via remote gitlab-runner and saving the image as an artifact... but they don't seem to appear. Is this feature only for self-hosted / paid Gitlab accounts? Can't exactly tell from the docs.

Comment: No, it's a free feature available for both shared and private (all kinds of) runners, We've never stumbled upon any issues with artifacts in GitLab.

Comment: Thanks for the help @trust512 -- the artifacts never showed up for me because the test run was failing. When I hacked it to temporarily succeed the artifacts showed up, finally giving me just enough insight into what's happening to start fixing things. I haven't tried the volume mapping approach below just yet, will report if I do.

Comment: Good to hear it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Continuing from comments*: You might register a runner with volume mapping to a host drive like:

**config.toml**

```
concurrent = 6
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "runner name"
  url = "******"
  token = "******"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:17.06.0-ce"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/srv/gitlab-runner/images:/usr/src/app/image-dir", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Note the `volumes` keyword above.

In case you need a hand with running dockerized gitlab-runner **with this volume specified**:

1. Setup a separate network for a runner:

   ```
   $ docker network create gitlab-runner-net
   ```
2. Run the main GitLab-runner docker container:

   ```
   $ sudo docker run -d \
   --name gitlab-runner \
   --privileged \
   --restart always \
   --network gitlab-runner-net \
   -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config.toml:/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml \
   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   -v /srv/gitlab-runner/images:/usr/src/app/image-dir
   -e DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
   gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
   ```
3. Register the runner with GitLab:

   ```
   $ docker run -it --rm \
   -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config.toml:/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml \
   gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine \
     register \
     --executor docker \
     --docker-image docker:17.06.0-ce \
     --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     --docker-volumes /srv/gitlab-runner/images:/usr/src/app/image-dir
   ```

And modify the runner's `config.toml` with the above volume mapping.

**Note**

The above configuration is not one-and-only, it's just a reference point to show how to map the volumes and in general how to set up a running dind runner as gitlab has some issues recently with setting up private runners.